# How can i manipulate all objects in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to set strokeWidth of all object in fabric js, but i cant find a way to manipulate all the objects on canvas, i tried creating a an array and pushing all items dropped on canvas to the array.

Comment: Please can you share some code to show what you've tried? Maybe someone can help you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `.getObjects()` method of canvas. I made an example for you here
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-curran-bkwtk?file=/src/index.js

```js
canvas.getObjects().forEach(obj => {
  obj.set({
    stroke: "brown",
    strokeWidth: 10
  });
});
```